# TeamCity изменяет права директории на root

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

Запускаю `TeamCity` вот так `sudo service teamcity start`.
В итоге у меня все так, вот я редактировал `1.txt` и сделал `build`
После сборки `1.txt` теперь принадлежит `root` и так же сменены права

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 jashka jashka 4096 апр  4 14:04 .
drwxrwxr-x. 17 jashka jashka 4096 апр  3 20:45 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root     24 апр  4 14:04 1.txt
drwxrwxrwx   8 jashka jashka 4096 апр  4 14:33 .git
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jashka jashka 1063 апр  3 20:55 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jashka jashka   27 апр  3 20:55 README.md
```

Почему так происходит и что сделать что бы не меняло права на директорию и файлы.

Второй вопрос. У меня есть репозиторий, создал я для него проект в `TeamCity` и хочу что бы на ветку `dev` работали одни крипты с `Build Step Command Line`, а на `master` будут работать другие скрипты.  Как это организовать, пока только знаю как сделать для 1 ветки

Comment: Какие шаги сборки вы используете? Под каким пользователем работает Teamcity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты  запускаешь сервис от имени рута. поэтому файл принадлежит руту.

`teamcity-server` в данном случае запускают от служебного пользователья, например, `teamcity`

```
sudo useradd -m teamcity
sudo chown -R teamcity /opt/TeamCity
sudo chown -R teamcity /opt/.BuildServer
```

создать файл  /etc/init.d/teamcity и прописать

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/teamcity -  startup script for teamcity
export TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH="/opt/.BuildServer"

case $1 in
  start)
    echo "Starting Team City"
    start-stop-daemon --start  -c teamcity --exec /srv/TeamCity/bin/teamcity-server.sh start
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping Team City"
    start-stop-daemon --start -c teamcity  --exec  /opt/TeamCity/bin/teamcity-server.sh stop
    ;;
  restart)
    echo "Restarting Team City"
    start-stop-daemon --start  -c teamcity --exec /opt/TeamCity/bin/teamcity-server.sh stop
    start-stop-daemon --start  -c teamcity --exec /opt/TeamCity/bin/teamcity-server.sh start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/teamcity {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

в конце дать права

```
sudo chown -R teamcity /opt/TeamCity
sudo chown -R teamcity /opt/.BuildServer
```

что касается второго вопроса, то вижу 2 решения

**1)**
скопирвоать весь проект на другую конфигурацию, указать дефолтный бранч, указать конкретные шаги...

минус в том. что нужно 2 конф-ии поддерживать

**2)** 
взять название баранча с параметра `teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID>`, подробно можно почитать [тут](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters), и использовать в Command Line для проверки. если мастер, то выполнить это, если dev, то другое

**UPDATE**

> Почему так происходит и что сделать что бы не меняло права на директорию и файлы.

если сервис не запускать от имени суперпользователья, то с большей вероятностью не сможешь выполнить некторые команды на машине, так как не будет прав на выполнения.

Вместо пользователья teamcity можно указывать своего, либо добавить в группу, куда ты входишь.

Comment: Боюсь, что смена владельца файла с `root` на `teamcity` никак не решит проблемы @jashka

Comment: @ZhukovRoman решит. если в юзеры в  одной группе

Comment: И не решит, если надо потом изменять `1.txt` пользователем `yashka`

Comment: а почему запускаете `teamcity-server`, а не `runAll.sh` ?

Comment: @jashka  runAll.sh запускает и сервер и агент

Comment: @ZhukovRoman если у группы есть доступ RW к этому файлу. то оба пользователья смогут

Comment: и да, еще этот репозиторий это фронт написан на `js`, и бекенд на `php`, я буду запускать веб-сервер, там юзер будет `nginx` или `www-data`. Как быть еще в таком случае ?

Comment: @jashka  у nginx  свои пользователи. вам надо с nginx-ом работать как сервис,  и nginx  должен иметь доступ туда, куда вы фронт развернули. на RHEL7 нет проблемы с nginx-ом, остальные более привередливы.  используйте package-manager для деплоя фронта, либо скопируйте в определенную папку, куда смотрит nginx и дайте права туда после этого